causality and locality in universe
In continuation to Mechanistic view of the universe my second question is does locality implies causality  and vice versa ? We have seen in previous question where causality sometimes locality doesn't hold  ..
Any example where locality holds but not causality
and causality holds but not locality

I think you should consider Kant's antinomies to understand that looking "out there" is going to reveal less than looking in. The antimonies are paradoxes of the distant view. There is still too much to be understood of the right here & now.

Causality and locality seem to me to be two ways of expressing something. Locality means something nearby affected something. Causality means something was affected by something. Nonlocal causality would probably look to us like randomness. Maybe that's what randomness is? Separated things affecting each other, or co-varying. All those elementary particles from the Big Bang, now 'randomly' decaying...

@ChrisDegnen write an answer please

From this post: Causality in space-like separated collapse of entangled pairs, this seems to be the most relevant take-away:  "How this works and why it works this way we cannot say with certainty."

... continuing the thoughts from the previous discussion ...
In a local system, causality is to be understood - in respect to time - as a flow of a cause and an effect. But if a system is non-local ie. gets influenced by others (in a non-linear by respect to  (local) time, way) it means that (some) causes are to be found outside of the local system. It is obvious then, that causality and non-locality are incompatible ... as a coherent "pack" of understanding that system.
In the reversed way, in a local system, all causes are to be found inside the system, and then this system could act as a cause to another etc. which is in fact what locality is.
In other words locality and causality - in the context of this discussion - are the two sides of the same coin, while non-locality, breaks the coin, and we have to come up with a new way of reconciling reality in our minds.

In Newton's theory of gravity, changes in the distribution of mass in one location change the gravitational field everywhere in space so that theory is causal but not local.
I should note that some of the answers and comments above are wrong.
General relativistic models with closed timelike curves can still be causal in the sense that the fields have an initial value formulation and the locality of the Einstein field equations imply locality:
https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.42.1915
Quantum theory without collapse is also both local and causal. (I won't comment on alternatives to quantum theory with collapse.) The equations of motion of relativistic quantum field theories are both local and causal. There is an entirely local explanation of how entanglement correlations arise. Quantum theory in the Heisenberg picture describes the evolution of measurable quantities in terms of operators called observables. The observables of one systems only change to be a function of those of another system as a result of local interactions. These operators describe multiple interfering versions of a system:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328
When you have done a measurement you only see one version of a system because spreading information about an observable prevents interference between different values of that observable: an effect called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
In the specific case of entanglement experiments the correlations arise as a result of quantum information being carried in decoherent channels without changing the expectation values of the observables of those systems. Since that information doesn't change the outcomes of measurements of the system in which it is carried it doesn't suffer decoherence and this locally inaccessible information is revealed only in entanglement correlations that arise when the comparison is made and not before:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

the Strong Censorship Conjecture is a profound hypothesis in general relativity that asserts the global determinism of spacetime and the inaccessibility of singularities, thereby preserving the predictive power of the theory

does locality implies causality and vice versa ?

Causality doesn't imply locality but since locality is about the manner in which one event can cause another locality implies causality.

any example of causality but not locality

@quanity See the first paragraph of my answer.

I mean that is wrong theory its breaks Lorentz transformation

@quanity Yes. Newtonian gravity is wrong.

@DikranMarsupial general relativity is a local theory of the gravitational field, Newtonian gravity is not.

Causality and locality are closely intertwined but in the quantum description of the world , causality and locality do not always go hand in hand. For example , in quantum entanglement , quantum field theories and general theory of relativity for time like loops.

No, actually, causality and locality remain intertwined in quantum field theory. Quantum entanglement is about correlation, not causation.
